# Downgrade from Xcode 6.1 to Xcode 5.1.1

Tags: xcode

I just accidentally updated Xcode to 6.0.1 (don't ask me how these things happen).

I'd like to downgrade - is there any clear path for that?

Comment: Try copying it back in from a backup - compress the new version by right clicking on it then choosing compress - then delete the uncompressed app - then copy the older version into applications folder from your backup. If you don't have a backup I have no suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up downloading from the developer site and trashing the old version. This seems to work.